# More than one variable on javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this script :

```
 <v-tab :title="siteObject.xip_infos[index].lineid" >
   <div class="description text-left" :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'DEACTIVE' }">
     <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
       <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
     </small>
   </div>
 </v-tab>
```

The result of this script shows me all item have status **DEACTIVE**.
I want to add the condition **disconnected**. How do i do this?

Comment: I am not sure why the heavy downvoting. Perhaps you need to show the expected output?

Comment: @mplungjan wen is deactive the output will be red i have allready the output with disconnected i just wanna put it on same class to be red thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi All i found the answer

```html
<v-tab :title="siteObject.xip_infos[index].lineid">
  <div class="description text-left" 
  :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'DEACTIVE' || item.status === 'DISCONNECTED'  }">
    <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
      <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
    </small>
  </div>
</v-tab>
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? If so, please mention this in the answer

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this maybe:

```
<v-tab :title="siteObject.xip_infos[index].lineid" >
  <div class="description text-left" 
    :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'DEACTIVE' || item.disconnected == true }">
     <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
       <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
     </small>
   </div>
</v-tab>
```

Comment: Like what is the "I want to add the condition disconnected. "? is "disconnected" a property?

Comment: its work now with this :           <div class="description text-left" :class="{ 'text-danger': item.status === 'DEACTIVE' || item.status === 'DISCONNECTED'  }">

Comment: well ok then :)